# How to query SQL Server using PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I found some code online but so far I can't get it to connect to my SQL Server database.  I have followed this website to the letter:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/walzenbach/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008/

I have allowed remote connections, added port 1433 to my firewall etc.  I then run this code from PowerShell ISE:

```
    $dataSource = “\\SCCM12-01\MSSQLSERVER”
    $user = “MyID\OurDomain.org”
    $pwd = “MyPassword”
    $database = “CM1”
    $connectionString = “Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=False;”

    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
    $connection.Open()
```

when I run this I get the following error.

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was 
>   not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection 
>   string is not valid)"

Comment: Try without the \\.

Comment: No, that does not work either.  When I remove the \\ I get this error:   Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was 
not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection 
string is not valid)"
At line:13 char:1
+ $connection.Open()

Comment: This is not usually a problem but I see many smart quotes `“”` in the code you have. Consider replacing those with real quotes `"`and let us know if that changes anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you have simple query to do I recommend [Select-SQLView](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ProductivityTools.PSSelectSQLView/) powershell module. It allows to quickly select rows from table or view. It stores your database and server name so you do not have to provide this values every time.

As usual You can push results to table or to GridView.

If more complex queries are needed use [SQLCommands](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ProductivityTools.PSSQLCommands/) module.

[image: Select-SQLView]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are getting this error. You can refer to this link [https://github.com/Tervis-Tumbler/InvokeSQL](http://Link)

You can try this one-

```
function Invoke-SQL {
    param(
        [string] $dataSource = ".\SQLEXPRESS",
        [string] $database = "MasterData",
        [string] $sqlCommand = $(throw "Please specify a query.")
      )

    $connectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource; " +
            "Integrated Security=SSPI; " +
            "Initial Catalog=$database"

    $connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
    $command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommand,$connection)
    $connection.Open()

    $adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command
    $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

    $connection.Close()
    $dataSet.Tables  
}
```

Comment: The OP is trying to use Sql Server authentication whilst your example is based on integrated Windows security. (Which is smarter, but not what's being asked.)

Answer (score 0):

The error message actually explains what's wrong:

> "SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - *Connection string is not valid*".

There is something amiss on the connection string. What exactly is hard to say as you have masked most of the details. Maybe the smart quotes wreck things? Maybe you got a quote character in the password? Anyway, it looks like you have [invalid parameter](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/standard-security/) for the user id:

```
$connectionString = “Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=False;”
```

Try `User Id` instead of `uid` like so,

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

You properly just need to change 'Integrated Security' to 'true' when not using a db login

```
**Integrated Security=True**
```